# How to extract list from inside a list?

Tags: python, list

I have working code that returns this list:

```
[[3016, 59, 951, 609], [1119, 54, 639, 1392], [1899, 32, 1081, 1603]]
[0, 0, 0]
[[3016, 59, 951, 609], [1119, 54, 639, 1392], [1899, 32, 1081, 1603]]
[0, 0, 0]
[[3016, 59, 951, 609], [1119, 54, 639, 1392], [1899, 32, 1081, 1603]]
[0, 0, 0]
[[3016, 59, 951, 609], [1119, 54, 639, 1392], [1899, 32, 1081, 1603]]
```

However, I am only interested in accessing the first numbers (3016, 1119 and 1899).

I have tried iterating through the list using

```
for i in list:
   val = list[i]
```

However, I get an error saying that an integer is expected inside the list, and not another list.
How can I access the numbers I wish to access? I will later also have to access the 3 others from each array.

Comment: "this list" are actually 7 lists.

Comment: What are the `[0, 0, 0]` elements? Are they regularly every other element?

Comment: the [0,0,0] elements correspond to the object type of each array. Since I only have 1 object type (0), I do not need them. They do come regularly, once for each object

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Should be something like this:

```
l_out = [[3016, 59, 951, 609], [1119, 54, 639, 1392], [1899, 32, 1081, 1603]]

for l_in in l_out:
    for element in l_in:
        val = element
```

Or just to access list items:

```
l_out = [[3016, 59, 951, 609], [1119, 54, 639, 1392], [1899, 32, 1081, 1603]]

l_1 = l[0]  # first list
element = l[0][0]  # first item from first list
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a list comprehension with even indices only -

```
my_list = [[[3016, 59, 951, 609], [1119, 54, 639, 1392], [1899, 32, 1081, 1603]],
[0, 0, 0],
[[3016, 59, 951, 609], [1119, 54, 639, 1392], [1899, 32, 1081, 1603]],
[0, 0, 0],
[[3016, 59, 951, 609], [1119, 54, 639, 1392], [1899, 32, 1081, 1603]],
[0, 0, 0],
[[3016, 59, 951, 609], [1119, 54, 639, 1392], [1899, 32, 1081, 1603]]]

only_first_elements = [[l[0] for l in l_] for l_ in my_list[::2]]
```

Also - Do not name a parameter `list`!

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this work:

```py
numlist = [[3016, 59, 951, 609], [1119, 54, 639, 1392], [1899, 32, 1081, 1603]]
i = 0
listout = []
for i_list in numlist :
    for number in i_list:
         if i == 0 :
              listout.append(number)
         i += 1
    i = 0
print(listout)
```